# Migrate session from memcached to redis without logging users out in laravel

Tags: laravel, session, redis, memcached

We're using Memcached to store Laravel's cookie-based session at the moment but want to use Redis throughout for session and cache for consistency.

Is there a way to migrate all user sessions from Memcached to Redis without logging out the users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to migrate the sessions without logging out the users. I created an artisan command for the purpose:

```
<?php
namespace App\Console\Commands;
use \Memcached;
use \Redis;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
class MigrateSessionToRedis extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'migrate:session';
    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Migrate sessions from Memcached to Redis';
    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct() #NOSONAR
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $this->info('Starting session migration..');
        $memcached = new Memcached();
        $memcached->addServer(env('MEMCACHED_HOST'), 11211);
        $sessions = $this->getMemcachedKeys(env('MEMCACHED_HOST'));
        if (! is_array($sessions)) {
            $this->error('Could not retrieve sessions from Memcached');
            exit(1);
        }
        foreach ($sessions as $session) {
            $value = $memcached->get($session);
            if ($value) {
                $object = unserialize($value);
                $valueForRedis = serialize(serialize($object));
                // Set session in Redis with session expiry lifetime
                Redis::set("{$session}", $valueForRedis, 'EX', config('session.lifetime'));
            }
        }
        $this->info('Finished session migration.');
    }
    /**
    * Get all memcached keys. Special function because getAllKeys() is broken since memcached 1.4.23.
    * Should only be needed on php 5.6
    *
    * cleaned up version of code found on Stackoverflow.com by Maduka Jayalath
    *
    * @return array|int - all retrieved keys (or negative number on error)
    */
    private function getMemcachedKeys($host = '127.0.0.1', $port = 11211) #NOSONAR
    {
        $mem = @fsockopen($host, $port);
        if ($mem === false) {
            return -1;
        }
        // retrieve distinct slab
        $r = @fwrite($mem, 'stats items' . chr(10));
        if ($r === false) {
            return -2;
        }
        $slab = [];
        while (($l = @fgets($mem, 1024)) !== false) {
            // finished?
            $l = trim($l);
            if ($l == 'END') {
                break;
            }
            $m = [];
            // <STAT items:22:evicted_nonzero 0>
            $r = preg_match('/^STAT\sitems\:(\d+)\:/', $l, $m);
            if ($r != 1) {
                return -3;
            }
            $a_slab = $m[1];
            if (!array_key_exists($a_slab, $slab)) {
                $slab[$a_slab] = [];
            }
        }
        reset($slab);
        foreach ($slab as $a_slab_key => &$a_slab) {
            $r = @fwrite($mem, 'stats cachedump ' . $a_slab_key . ' 100' . chr(10));
            if ($r === false) {
                return -4;
            }
            while (($l = @fgets($mem, 1024)) !== false) {
                // finished?
                $l = trim($l);
                if ($l == 'END') {
                    break;
                }
                $m = [];
                // ITEM 42 [118 b; 1354717302 s]
                $r = preg_match('/^ITEM\s([^\s]+)\s/', $l, $m);
                if ($r != 1) {
                    return -5;
                }
                $a_key = $m[1];
                $a_slab[] = $a_key;
            }
        }
        // close the connection
        @fclose($mem);
        unset($mem);
        $keys = [];
        reset($slab);
        foreach ($slab as &$a_slab) {
            reset($a_slab);
            foreach ($a_slab as &$a_key) {
                $keys[] = $a_key;
            }
        }
        unset($slab);
        return $keys;
    }
}
```

Hope it can help others.

Comment: your idea was helpful to me

Answer (score 0):

Below just example how to make this kind of migration. Try it that way:

```
<?php

$host = '127.0.0.1';
$port = null;
$oldPrefix = 'sess_';
$newPrefix = 'sess_';
$sessionDir = '/var/lib/php/session/';
$m = new \Redis();
$m->connect($host, $port);
// $m = new \Memcached();
// $m->addServer($host, $port);
$sessions = scandir($sessionDir);
if (!$sessions) {
    die('nothing to migrate');
}
foreach ($sessions as $s) {
    if (in_array($s, ['.', '..'])) {
        continue;
    }
    $sessionName = str_replace($oldPrefix, '', $s);
    $sessionContents = file_get_contents($sessionDir.$s);
    if (!$m->set($newPrefix.$sessionName, $sessionContents)) {
        die(sprintf('Could not migrate session %s'.PHP_EOL, $newPrefix.$sessionName));
    }
    echo '.';
}
die(PHP_EOL);
```

But I guess hat users will be logged out.

Comment: The most important point is keeping them logged in. Their existing cookie should not be invalidated.